# R: Validate matches of coresponding column values (ID and name) and flag inconsistencies, ideally in dplyr

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, match, lookup

Imagine you have a data frame with hundreds of products and another data frame with thousands of sales (see simplified data below). Each product has a name and an ID. Unfortunately, in the sales data, some inconsistencies exist between product name and id (see observation 3). How can I identify and flag these inconsistencies in an automated manner, for e.g. by adding a column highlighting these inconsistencies (see example below). Best would be to integrate in my dplyr data manipulation work flow.

Pls note that the data is a bit messy and ***some orders combine multiple products (see obs. 4).*** I thought of a loop in combination with grepl.

```
# products
P_names <- c( 'ProductA', 'ProductB')
P_ID <- c('p1', 'p2')
Product_list <- data.frame(P_names, P_ID)

   P_names P_ID
1 ProductA   p1
2 ProductB   p2

# sales data
P_n_sales <- c('ProductA', 'ProductB', 'ProductB', 'ProductA, ProductB', 'ProductB, ProductA')
P_ID_sales  <- c('p1', 'p2', 'p1', 'p1, p1', 'p1, p2')
sales_data <- data.frame(P_n_sales, P_ID_sales)

          P_n_sales P_ID_sales
1           ProductA         p1
2           ProductB         p2
3           ProductB         p1
4 ProductA, ProductB     p1, p1
5 ProductB, ProductA     p1, p2
```

Desired output:

```
           P_n_sales P_ID_sales Incons.
1           ProductA         p1  corect
2           ProductB         p2  corect
3           ProductB         p1   error
4 ProductA, ProductB     p1, p1   error
5 ProductB, ProductA     p1, p2 correct
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for your replies. However, even though the solutions presented above seem to run much faster, they did not consider that data (product IDs & names) may be entered in wrong orders.

I was more looking for something like:

```
library(dplyr)
##
for (n in 1:nrow(Product_list)){
 sales_data<-sales_data%>%
 dplyr::mutate(Incons = ifelse(
                                (grepl(Product_list$P_names[n], sales_data$P_n_sales)
                                &!grepl(Product_list$P_ID[n], sales_data$P_ID_sales))
                                |
                                (!grepl(Product_list$P_names[n], sales_data$P_n_sales)
                                &grepl(Product_list$P_ID[n], sales_data$P_ID_sales))
                               ,paste('error')
                                ,paste('correct')
                                ))
}
```

Depending on the complexity of the data it may require additional regex specification within the `grepl()`, such as escaping special characters, word bound, ...

Does anyone have a more efficient approach than looping over the data (it takes quite some time for large data)?

Answer (score 1):

I think simply `%in%` will do it

```
Sales_data %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(P_n_sales, P_ID_sales) %>%
  mutate(Incons. = paste(P_n_sales, P_ID_sales) %in% paste(Product_list$P_names, Product_list$P_ID)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Incons. = ifelse(min(Incons.) == 0, "Incorr", "Corr")) %>%
  left_join(Sales_data %>% mutate(id = row_number()))


# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id Incons. P_n_sales          P_ID_sales
  <int> <chr>   <chr>              <chr>     
1     1 Corr    ProductA           p1        
2     2 Corr    ProductB           p2        
3     3 Incorr  ProductB           p1        
4     4 Incorr  ProductA, ProductB p1, p1
```

Comment: Sorry, I had simplified my example too much (see edits above).

Comment: since the data is joining back with itself, I think you may get all your columns back.

Comment: Still, there are observations in my data that I do not classify correctly. see adapted example. I would classify observation 4 as correct as the names match the id  even though they are not in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a left/right join and change the value to `'error'` for combination that do not exist in `Sales_data`.

```
library(dplyr)

Sales_data %>%
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(P_n_sales, P_ID_sales, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  left_join(Product_list %>% mutate(Incons = 'correct'), 
            by = c('P_n_sales' = 'P_names', 'P_ID_sales' = 'P_ID')) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarise(across(c(P_n_sales, P_ID_sales), toString),
            Incons = if(any(is.na(Incons))) 'error' else 'correct') %>%
  select(-rowid)

#  P_n_sales          P_ID_sales Incons 
#  <chr>              <chr>      <chr>  
#1 ProductA           p1         correct
#2 ProductB           p2         correct
#3 ProductB           p1         error  
#4 ProductA, ProductB p1, p1     error
```

Comment: Sorry, I had simplified my example too much (see edits above).

Comment: @MrGISRocker Updated the answer based on your new data.

Comment: Still, there are observations in my data that I do not classify correctly. see adapted example. I would classify observation 4 as correct as the names match the id even though they are not in the same order.